# How to do mathematical calculation inside foreach loop?

Tags: php

I am new to php, I have a function to do sum. Heres below:

```
<?php
class math {
    public function add($data) { // add("1,2,3") separated by comma
        $data=explode(",", $data);
        foreach($data as $val){
            echo $val +=$val;
        }
        return $val;
    }

}
$class_math = new math;
echo $class_math->add("1,2,3,4");
?>
```

But this should give result =10, but it is giving result 8, where's the error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overwriting the value of `$val` in your loop.

```
public function add($data) { // add("1,2,3") separated by comma
    $data=explode(",", $data);
    $total = 0;
    foreach($data as $val){
        echo $total+=$val;
    }
    return $total;
}
```

FYI, an easier way to do this might be to use [`array_sum()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
public function add($data) { // add("1,2,3") separated by comma
    $data=explode(",", $data);
    return array_sum($data);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a duplicate variable name: `$val`

```
public function add($data) { // add("1,2,3") separated by comma
    $collect = 0;
    $data=explode(",", $data);
    foreach($data as $val){
        $collect += $val;
    }
    return $collect;
}
```

In the last iteration `$val` is `4`, so it does `4+4=8`